# Should right take precedence over left in all regards?

Tags: halacha

We all know the famous Halacha that you need to put in your right shoe first, and remove it last to give kavod to the right foot.

Similarly, the Gemara mentions reasons of why the right hand should get kavod and not be used to wipe yourself (you use it to point in the Torah, etc…)

So my question is does this idea of giving precedence to the right side by doing that side first apply to all areas in life? Is it necessary to put in my right contact lense first? Do I need to pick up the right dumbbell first, and place it down last? Or does this only apply to shoes?

Comment: https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/precedence-of-right-side/

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3230609/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-2-Laws-Relating-to-Dressing.htm#v4